# Triggers are not detecting colliders from other game objects in Unity version 5.2.2f1?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, physics, unity

I was working on a basic slots game, and I came across a hiccup with the 2D Physics engine. Currently I'm letting the reels spin for three seconds. Once it has finished spinning, it will go to the reel stop that the RGN picked out. Also, when it has reached the end of the reel I had it so that reel would "wrap around" to the firs reel stop continuing displaying the stops as it before.

I'm using a edge collider as a trigger on each reel (I'll call it a symbol trigger for short). The symbol trigger is a child of the reel but the actual symbols (which are game objects in screen space) are procedural generated and attached to the actual reel. All the symbols have a rigidbody2D and are kinematic. For some reason the triggers do no respond with on enter, on stay, or on exit, and that is with putting debug logs.

Now I have taken the reels and triggers to and out of world space and screen space, switched from rigidbody2D to 3D along with, messed with the sleep options, and switched it from discreet to continuous and still have get no response from the collider. If anyone knows why this is happening, your insight would be highly  appreciated!

Thanks for reading about my issue and have a good day.

Comment: Yes, 2D physics exists in Unity. You need to provide more details (see the minimal, complete, verifiable example link above).

Comment: Sorry that I phrased the title of this discussion in a weird way. What I'm trying to get at is that I'm having a problem with registering triggers in Unity using 2D colliders and 2D rigid bodies. For example, if I am translating a game object that has a rigid body down though a static collider it should trigger that there was something that has passed. I can't seem to make the colliders register a game object has passed though it.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the OnTriigerEnter2D() etc variants?